# Roots of polynomial equations

Tags: polynomials, roots

Is there anything that can be said about the roots of the polynomial $f_n(x)$ if $f_n(x) = xf_{n-1}(x) + f_{n-2}(x)$ where these are polynomials of degree $n, n-1,$ and $n-2$, respectively. In addition, the roots of both $f_{n-1}(x)$ and $f_{n-2}(x)$ are known to be the maximum number of complex conjugate pairs (at most one purely real root), and all roots have positive real part.

Comment: These are the [Fibonacci polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_polynomials). See the paper ["Roots of Fibonacci polynomials"](http://www.fq.math.ca/11-3.html) mentioned in that page.

Comment: ... depending on $f_0$ and $f_1$.

Comment: @lhf Unfortunately, I'm not dealing with Fibonacci polynomials. For me,  $
f_1(x) = x - 1$, and  $f_2(x) = x^2 - x + 1$